# Запуск активити другого приложения

Tags: android

Есть приложение А, в нем стандартная активность
com.example.messer.myapplicationa

Есть приложение B, в нем тоже стандартная активность 
com.example.messer.myapplicationb

Нужно переслать строку из А в В

```
           Intent i = new Intent(com.example.messer.myapplicationb);
            i.putExtra("string", editText.getText());
            startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Что передавать в интент? Не могу найти никак

Answer (score 4):

Передаете Вашу строку из приложения А в MainActivity приложения Б:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent();
myIntent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.messer.myapplicationb", "com.example.messer.myapplicationb.MainActivity"));
myIntent1.putExtra("param1", myEditText1.getText().toString());
startActivity(myIntent1);
```

В приложении Б в MainActivity в методе onCreate принимаете переданную строку:

```
String myParametrFromApplicationA = getIntent().getStringExtra("param1");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myParametrFromApplicationA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/intents/filters.html), еще [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/64-urok-26-intent-filter-praktika)